# document.ready disables other function if on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions that are working perfectly, except when i put them on the same page.

Function 1: - this will call a php to update the change and stops working when it's on the same page with the second one

```
<script>
    function save() {
        if (document.myform.notify1.checked == true) {
            var value1 = 1;
        } else {
            var value1 = 0;
        }
        if (document.myform.notify2.checked == true) {
            var value2 = 1;
        } else {
            var value2 = 0;
        }

        $.post('save_settings.php', {
            notify1: value1,
            notify2: value2
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Function 2: - this one calls a list in case of the result and always works

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#list").load("list.php");
        setInterval(function () {
            $.get('check.php', function (result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                    $("#list").load("list.php");
                }
            });
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

and here is the form that calls function save().

```
<form action="settings.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" id="myform" method="post">

<input class="check" name="notify1" type="checkbox" id="notify1" <?php if($notify1 == "1") { echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?> value="1" onchange="save();"/>

<input class="check" name="notify2" type="checkbox" id="notify2" <?php if($notify2 == "1") { echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?> value="1" onchange="save();"/>

</form>
```

Comment: How do you put them together in the same page?

Comment: Where is the element with `id="list"` in your HTML?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?  If a syntax error somewhere in the middle of your code is found, it would cause the rest of the code to not load.

Comment: for winterblood: <body> <div id="list"></div> </body> and there are no errors in syntax, like i said.. both functions work perfect by them selfs, only when i put them in same page function 1 stops working

Comment: I seems to be working fine. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhfyW/

Comment: yep.. seems so.  zeroed in on if(document.myform.notify1.checked == true) part... if i remove or replace this lines of code it works.. is there an alternative to check a checkbox in javascript ?

Comment: Everything seems to AOK. Only thing that is wrong is you are local scoping value1 and value2. You must scope it at the function level not at the condition level. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhfyW/1/

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is why do you want to use pure javascript and also jquery at the same time? If you are going to load jQuery anyhow then why not use jquery to get checkbox values as well.

Comment: good point, i'm just more used to javascript.. damn, i'll try that

Comment: yep.. jquery did it. if($("#notify1").is(':checked'))

Comment: @Yogesh: That doesn't matter, you can place `var` everywhere (and as often as you want) in the function scope. Admittedly, something short like `var value1 = Number(document.myform.notify1.checked)` would've been nicer, but the current function works flawless

Comment: @Bergi: I was thought that variable should only be declared once. I would like to learn if it is a good idea to have multiple "var" or just once for each variable?

Comment: @Yogesh: Not that it's a good practise (except maybe in `for(var i=0;…`-loops), no, but it is not an *error* that would lead to such problems. Having multiple var statements for the same variable in the same scope does declare in for that scope just as a single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep.. jquery did it. replaceing this:
if(document.myform.notify1.checked == true) with this if($("#notify1").is(':checked')) made it work.

```
<script>
    function save() {
        if ($("#notify1").is(':checked')) {
            var value1 = 1;
        } else {
            var value1 = 0;
        }
        if ($("#notify2").is(':checked')) {
            var value2 = 1;
        } else {
            var value2 = 0;
        }

        $.post('save_settings.php', {
            notify1: value1,
            notify2: value2
        });
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

thanks guys